# Objective-C Twitter 1.1 API Application-only Authentication 403 Forbidden

Tags: api, twitter

I'm attempting to update an iPhone app for the new (1.1) Twitter API.  I'd like to use Application-only Authentication, so that a user of the app does not need their own twitter account.  I created a twitter app, and am encoding the consumer key & secret before attempting to authenticate:

```
NSString *consumerKey = @"xxxxxxxxxxxx";
NSString *consumerSecret = @"yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

NSString *consumerKeyRFC1738 = [consumerKey stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
 NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *consumerSecretRFC1738 = [consumerSecret stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                   NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString *concatKeySecret = [[consumerKeyRFC1738 stringByAppendingString:@":"]    stringByAppendingString:consumerSecretRFC1738];

NSLog(@"concatKeySecret:%@", concatKeySecret);

NSString *concatKeySecretBase64 = [concatKeySecret base64EncodedString];

NSLog(@"concatKeySecretBase64:%@", concatKeySecretBase64);


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest
                                requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token"]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[@"Basic " stringByAppendingString:concatKeySecretBase64] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSString *str = @"grant-type=client_credentials";
NSData *httpBody = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:httpBody];

NSLog(@"Request:%@",request);

//NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: &response error: nil];

if ([response respondsToSelector:@selector(allHeaderFields)]) {
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];
    NSLog([dictionary description]);
    //NSLog(@"ETAG:%@",[dictionary valueForKey:@"ETag"]);
}
```

The response I receive is a 403 error.  Am I formatting my HTTP post correctly?

```
{
"Cache-Control" = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 118;
"Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
Date = "Tue, 30 Jul 2013 17:26:47 GMT";
Expires = "Tue, 31 Mar 1981 05:00:00 GMT";
"Last-Modified" = "Tue, 30 Jul 2013 17:26:47 GMT";
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = tfe;
"Set-Cookie" = "_twitter_sess=BAh7CDoMY3NyZl9pZCIlYWEwY2Y2NzU2NmQ3MjFjMTAyZmY2ZGFlNjFiZWNj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0X1.67F4B01F90C18P-881MjQ6B2lkIiUzNmQ1YTE1ZDQxZTFiN2Q0MTFjNzY2MmI5YTE2NDVkYToPY3Jl                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0X1.7FFFB87P-1043YXRlZF9hdGwrCMQunjBAAQ                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1371904                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -1776385004--7706e5d6c3e090acdab9a3c94d433e11eab2b48b; domain=.twitter.com; path=/; HttpOnly";
Status = "403 Forbidden";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=631138519";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"x-frame-options" = DENY;
"x-mid" = 62d49efa6db6ee537df4e330e351d93fbd0cf900;
"x-runtime" = "0.01460";
"x-transaction" = 49b51f5559838ae4;
"x-ua-compatible" = "IE=10,chrome=1";
"x-xss-protection" = "1; mode=block";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"grant-type=client_credentials";
```

should have been

```
NSString *str = @"grant_type=client_credentials";
```

note the underscore, instead of the hyphen!